# How do I make my docker image get custom argument at run command?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I dont know if this is possible and I looked for it in the docker documents. I couldnt figure out the way to do it. I need to pass some arguments to my docker image on the run command as follows:

```
$ docker run myimage --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2
```

So I can access these in my docker file. I have doubt that docker file is read during build but I need the argument during run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref : [passing-an-argument-to-the-interactive-docker-container-upon-its-launch](http://linuxconfig.org/passing-an-argument-to-the-interactive-docker-container-upon-its-launch)

Comment: Thanks. so to send the argument to a bash file, passing the file to entrypoint works?

Comment: it works. thanks. sorry for choosing answer late. :)